# Django: is it possible to specify accept method for a view in urls

Tags: python, django, url, url-routing

I'm curious about setting urls `accept_method` directly when defining url like

```
url(r'some-pattern', 'view_name', name='url_name', accept_method='GET|POST')
```

I know there're view decorators like `require_GET`, `require_POST` etc.

Is there any solutions for Django or any extension to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pratik Mandrekar thanks for definitive information and documentation.

I've created a small application which does this kind of job https://github.com/imanhodjaev/django-besmart-common

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done using django middleware.

Use [Process Request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-request) to intercept the requests.

> It should return either None or an HttpResponse object. If it returns
>   None, Django will continue processing this request, executing any
>   other process_request() middleware, then, process_view() middleware,
>   and finally, the appropriate view. If it returns an HttpResponse
>   object, Django won't bother calling any other request, view or
>   exception middleware, or the appropriate view; it'll apply response
>   middleware to that HttpResponse, and return the result.

`HttpRequest` has a `path` attribute which contains the url. Use that url to lookup the `urlconf` and check the `urlconf` params for the `accept-method` and return `None` or the same `HttpResponse` accordingly.